# Getting ListBox Selected Item DataContext Value

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, datacontext, listboxitem

If I have a listbox that contains the following Microsoft Word Color Indexes, how do I then get it's value and set it as a color index?

```
<ListBox x:Name="FindColorListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="135" Margin="10,198,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107">
    <ListBoxItem Content="None">
        <ListBoxItem.DataContext>
            <word:WdColorIndex>wdAuto</word:WdColorIndex>
        </ListBoxItem.DataContext>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Auto">
        <ListBoxItem.DataContext>
            <word:WdColorIndex>wdAuto</word:WdColorIndex>
        </ListBoxItem.DataContext>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Black">
        <ListBoxItem.DataContext>
            <word:WdColorIndex>wdBlack</word:WdColorIndex>
        </ListBoxItem.DataContext>
    </ListBoxItem>
</listbox>
```

So user clicks a "FindColorListBox" item, say "Black", and I want to get the `Word.WdColorIndex.Black` from the `datacontext` in order to set

```
find.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlack
```

Basically I'd think it's something like:

```
find.ColorIndex = FindColorListBox.SelectedItem.DataContext;
```

But obviously that isn't right...

Comment: I think I got it, I have to cast it: (Word.WdColorIndex)FindColorListBox.SelectedIndex;

Comment: Nope that isn't working correctly that's just grabbing the index value and attempting to cast it but it's not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you almost have it:

```
var selectedColorIndex = (Word.WdColorIndex)(((FrameworkElement) 
     (FindColorListBox.SelectedItem)).DataContext)
```